# Tactical challenge #2 - Attacking the kingside

Tags: tactics, checkmate, problems

The previous challenge was solved very quickly so here I am with a new one. Still a very easy one but hopefully a bit more challenging that the previous one. Black has just played Qb6 and it is White's turn. **What move should White do to win the game?**

```
[FEN "r3brk1/pp3pp1/1qn4p/3B4/8/P1R2N2/1PQ2PPP/3R2K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

I saw this puzzle from Chess24 Tactics Trainer and I liked it, so I decided to post it here.

Comment: This is a very simple puzzle. I'm not sure it can be counted as a challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `1. Ng5` threatening `Qh7#`
>  `1... hxg5 2.Rh3`
>  `1... g6 2. Qxg6`